# kotlin can sub class override base class's 'internal function?

Tags: kotlin, access-modifiers

A base class has **protected** function func_1, and **internal** function func_2

```
open class Base {

  protected open func_1() {
    printLin("in base func_1()")
  }

  internal open func_2() {
    printLin("in base func_2()")
  }

  fun run() {
     func_1()
     func_2()
  }
}
```

and would like to override them in the sub class

```
class SubClass {

  override func_1() {
     printLin("in sub func_1()")
  }

  override func_2() {
     printLin("in sub func_2()")
  }
}
```

question, is the **internal** behavior same the **protected**, in terms of the child class can override it same as the protected ones? in what case the **internal** would be better to use than **protected**?

Comment: `internal` is visible to everything inside the same module, while `protected` is only visible to the class itself and its subclasses. You can read more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces

Comment: You cannot override an `internal` function if your subclass is in a different module.

Comment: thanks! doc only says the visibility of the internal in inside the module,  but does not say whether it is same as protected in terms of inheritance. @Fureeish I guess it is implicitly saying that if the subclass is out side the module it does not have the visibility, so cant override. But besides that overriding it is sub class is same to do with the protected.